# C memory leak despite free

Tags: c, memory, pointers, valgrind

In debugging my program with Valgrind, I have discovered a memory leak despite what I thought were effective calls to free.  First, the code that is allocating the memory and storing it:

```
    row = malloc(sizeof(Row));
    row->columns = malloc(sizeof(char*) * headcnt);
    row->numcol  = 0;

    ...

    row->numcol    = colcnt;
    rows           = realloc(rows, (rowcnt+1) * sizeof(Row));
    rows[rowcnt++] = *row;
```

The code responsible for attempting to free the memory:

```
void cleanUp(){
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < rowcnt; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < rows[i].numcols; j++){
            free(rows[i].columns[j]);
        }
        free(&rows[i]);
    }
    free(rows); 
    exit(0);
}
```

The declaration of Row:

```
typedef struct {
    char** columns;
    unsigned short int numcol;
} Row;

Row* rows = NULL;
```

Worse still, this program sometimes causes a glibc error at `free(&rows[i])` that complains of a double free.  I am new to C, and would appreciate any pointers (ahem) someone might have.

Comment: You need to include the declaration of the Row type.

Comment: Could do with more of the code here. At the moment I'm a bit confused why you `malloc` space for each column in a row then set row->numcol to zero.

Comment: `free()` knows the block size of memory that `malloc()` allocated and will deallocate the whole block. It looks like you are iterating over the block and try to deallocate parts of the memory block.

Comment: @ustun: I like clang too, but how would this help here?

Comment: @Lucas I'm not sure, but clang static analyzer (not the compiler) sometimes helps with memory leaks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Doing `rows[rowcnt++] = *row;` effectively makes a copy of the memory you allocated. Your array rows should be an array of pointers. Also like Oli Chalesworth pointed out, you free for columns should be a single free for all the columns.

```
rows = malloc(count * sizeof(Row*)); // This is probably done somewhere

row->columns = malloc(sizeof(char*) * headcnt);
row->numcol  = 0;

...

row->numcol    = colcnt;
rows           = realloc(rows, (rowcnt+1) * sizeof(Row*));
rows[rowcnt++] = row;
```

Now if your cleanup

```
void cleanUp(){
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < rowcnt; i++){
        free(rows[i]->columns);
    }
    free(rows); 
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Every call to `malloc` (or `realloc`) must be matched with a corresponding call to `free`.  If you dynamically allocate an array thus:

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) * NUM);
```

You free it like this:

```
free(p);
```

Not like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
{
    free(p[i]);
}
```

It appears that you are doing this incorrectly.  I *suspect* that your cleanup code ought to be:

```
void cleanUp(){
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < rowcnt; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < rows[i].numcols; j++){
            free(rows[i].columns[j]); // Free whatever rows[i].columns[j] points to
        }
        free(rows[i].columns); // Matches row->columns = malloc(sizeof(char*) * headcnt);
    }
    free(rows);  // Matches rows = realloc(rows, (rowcnt+1) * sizeof(Row));
    exit(0);
}
```

Also, there is no way to match the `row = malloc(sizeof(Row));`.  I *suspect* that your allocation code ought to be:

```
row->numcol    = colcnt;
rows           = realloc(rows, (rowcnt+1) * sizeof(Row));
rows[rowcnt].columns = malloc(sizeof(char*) * headcnt);
rows[rowcnt].numcol = 0;
rowcnt++;
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer cleared up my misconception on freeing dynamically allocated arrays.

Answer (score -6):

Maybe I'm being dense, but isn't this totally unnecessary? All of your memory will be released as soon as the program exits, anyway.

Comment: This is true, but I have been given the stink eye by veteran C programmers for raising this point before.

Comment: Maybe, but it's considered good practice to clear up anyway.  Consider what happens if you decide in the future to convert the application to a library, or a function.

Comment: Which is fair, because if you don't tidy up this memory then how are you supposed to spot *real* memory leaks when they occur? It's like having 50 warnings from the compiler that you ignore because you know they are "okay". When warning 51 shows up it just gets lost in the noise.

Comment: The question is then what happens when you run out of memory during execution? If you're losing memory during the lifetime of your program on data that you cannot access anymore, you have the potential to waste lots of non-required memory. Sure, it will be freed at the end of the program, eventually, but what if that program is run indefinitely? I think that's why the issue of freeing memory becomes important.

Comment: @Tyler Eaves this not good thinking..what if the program is a daemon/server and isn't supposed to exit?

Comment: That's not what the OPs code does. When the frees are all in a function called cleanup() that ends with exit(0) I think it's pretty clear it's not a daemon.

Comment: @Tyler Eaves you can't figure that out so simple..maybe what the op posted is only a subset of a bigger application?

Comment: And maybe I'm a space alien. OPs question makes the context abundantly clear. There's no reason to start throwing hypotheticals out.

Comment: @Tyler Eaves I'm not trying to start a hypothetical war, instead i am trying to figure out how exactly did you find out what the op's application life span is and does on a bigger picture?

Comment: @Shinnok: doesn't matter if it's part of a bigger application - `exit()` semantics won't be changed by that...

Comment: +1: manually calling `free()` unecessarily ties up resources, and, speaking from experience, the processing caused by manual deallocation can be significant; however, as always, all bets are off on embedded (or otherwise exotic) environments; also, manual deallocation may expose heap corruption, so it might be a good idea to enable it for debug builds...

Comment: To end the discussion in a clear matter, the issue of freeing or not  doesn't matter at all in this question's context. The OP asked specifically how to correctly free the used space and not if he should or should not free it. :-)

Comment: "doesn't matter if it's part of a bigger application - exit() semantics won't be changed by that..." -- missing the point; in  a real application, exit may be called much later. "manually calling free() unecessarily ties up resources" -- What the heck are you talking about?

Comment: "maybe what the op posted is only a subset of a bigger application?" ... "And maybe I'm a space alien." -- What the OP posted may in fact be only a subset of a bigger application, whereas there's no chance that you're a space alien ... but if you are one, you're a rude one.

Comment: @Jim: allocate a huge linked-list with one `malloc()` per node; exit the application with and without explicit deallocation while looking at the cpu monitor; granted, using a less insane allocation strategy would have mitigated the issue, but the point still stands: bulk-deallocation by the OS is more efficient than individual deallocation through libc

Comment: @Christoph "granted, using a less insane allocation strategy would have mitigated the issue" -- Funny how people are all hot about what the OP code literally does one moment and then don't care about it the next moment. Anyway, the key word in your statement was "unnecessarily" -- some people consider it necessary not to leak memory.

Comment: @Jim: as to your second comment: "The code responsible for attempting to free the memory" implies - at least to me - that the code was taken (more-or-less) verbatim from the application; and unnecessarily accusing people of rude behaviour is.. quite rude ;) chill...

Comment: @Christoph If SO had a plonk, I would apply it to you. Goodbye.

Comment: Every time I chased a memory leak I found a serious bug that wasn't clear before the chase. A memory leak results from a false assumption somewhere in your program, i.e. you got it wrong whose job it was to clean up, this often means that the whole thing was not well thought out and other things are probably wrong also.